# Using static method and retrieving data from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am not sure whether I am doing wrong thing or not regarding the following codes.
Using static and instantiating sqlConnection and retrieving data from database.

```
public static DataSet GetSiteSummary(DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? toDate)
    {
        string connectionString = Configuration.DBCon;

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();

            SqlParameter paramFromDate = new SqlParameter("@fromDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            paramFromDate.Value = fromDate;

            SqlParameter paramToDate = new SqlParameter("@toDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            paramToDate.Value = toDate;

            ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(con, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetSiteSummary", paramFromDate, paramToDate);
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ErrorLog eLog = new ErrorLog();
            eLog.InserErrorLog("GetSiteSummary", "System", e);
            eLog.Dispose();
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

Comment: What *exactly* is your question ? is your code not working as expected ? are you asking question about best practices for database connections, commands ?

Comment: Your SQLConnection and `ErrorLog` should be in `using` blocks, and I question whether you want to just log and ignore the error. The caller might want to _know_ that the `DataSet` will be empty.

Comment: I've used static method and calling database calls

Comment: Also, this method causes sql deadlock errors.

Comment: @coder That's partly why John recommended you use `using` blocks. And you still didn't answer Habib's question about what exactly is not working as expected.

Comment: If you're getting deadlocks, then it will be due to the stored procedure, not this code.